# How to show fullsize images in scroll view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application suppose to show images in full screen and i have lots of images in my list(more than 500 images).

I'm adding image view in scroll view with horizontal scrolling and paging. But I'm facing memory issues as loaded images will eat my device memory?

What is the best way to load images.
[image]

Comment: Use UICollectionView instead of UIScrollView for handle memory consumption issue.

Comment: You can use `UICollectionView` and enable horizontal paging.

Comment: okay... I think collectionview is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't attempt to use a vanilla `UIScrollView` to show a ton of content, especially if you're just going to dump it all in at load-time. As you've seen, that will inevitably crash due to memory pressure.

At a minimum use `UICollectionView`, which will at least reuse cells and allow a minimum of assets to be in memory at one time. However, the problem of a smooth, low-memory photo collection view is one that many apps encounter, and can have a lot of implementation gotchas. I recommend looking for a well-built component rather than trying to reinvent that particular wheel.